# error while retrieving date oracle oracle DB using java timestamp

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, timestamp

I am having a basic select query with beanproperty mapper(spring boot) to map the data to a bean. the mapping works fine in some environments, but in some environments, the year in date is getting converted wrongly like 0020 instead of 2020.

```java
String sql = "SELECT ENDPOINT AS \"url\",LAST_REPORTED AS \"lastReported\" FROM NODE WHERE CLUSTER_ID=? AND STATUS=?";
return jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new Object[] { clusterId, "ACTIVE"}, new BeanPropertyRowMapper(nodeListMapper.class));
```

Mapper :

```java
public class nodeListMapper {
    
    private String url;
    private Timestamp lastReported;
    
    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }
    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }
    public Timestamp getLastReported() {
        return lastReported;
    }
    public void setLastReported(Timestamp lastReported) {
        this.lastReported = lastReported;
    }
}
```

The value in DB is '13-JUL-20 11.21.07.725000000 AM' In some DB instances the date is retrieved as '0020-07-13 11:21:07.725' instead of '2020-07-13 11:21:07.725'